# How to save everybody's result in a text file?

Tags: java, javascript, html, web-applications

I am a engineering student. Yesterday only i got my result for my final result.

I want too write a script to get the data for all the students, i have the registration codes already

LINK

http://academics.vit.ac.in/coe/result/results.asp?exammode=Regular&examh=May-2011&flag=n

So i am finding  a way to write a Java or c# program to store all results.

After pressing the submit button, registration number is not being passed in URL,
otherwise it could have easily done using DOBuilder.

Comment: if not in the url maybe in post?

Comment: i am not getting you. I looked at it html code.i am not able to find out anything.

Comment: in this form the value `regno` is passed using POST so you will pass it using your script

Comment: i dont think it is nice to expose all the students result here for anyone to access, maybe you should take out the code

Comment: Is there is any sample program that can help me?

Comment: to do a request in java http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/HttppostmethodExample.htm

Comment: thanks ..i will try and let u know..

Answer (score 2):

The form has a method of "POST" - so the registration number is in the body of the HTTP request. If you use [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com) or [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) you'll be able to see exactly what it's doing pretty easily.

You're probably best off using a library such as [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to populate the post body within Java.

Just to check - are you *allowed* to retrieve other students' results?

Comment: ya..we are allowed to see everybody's result..they are our friends only..if we are not allowed to see other's result, then they would have given username and password.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : i dont know what is Fiddler and Wireshark.

Comment: They're programs that allow you to see exactly what's being transmitted on your net connection.

Comment: @ Dr.Dredel - Will u please elaborate..??

Comment: @Vik: Did you try following the links I helpfully provided?